# Source not found exception

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload

In my application i have a JSP file named "Transferdatanew.jsp". When I am going to use my application, I am getting an exception as `numberformatexception`, but when I clicked there I am getting a message as "source not found for org.apache.jsp._Transferdatanew".

What does this mean? Please help me. I am new to Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number format exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364004/number-format-exception)

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty clear that there is a problem in the 'Transferdatanew.jsp'.   I'd venture so far as to say that the jsp is receiving an input that is not in the numerical format it expects.

You should not be worried about 'Source not found exception' unless you want to see the source .... which will be in one of the $TOMCAT_HOME/work subfolders.

Comment: ..............................   <%if(tableChFlag.equals("Y")){%>
   System.out.println("tableChFlag.equals("Y")");
alert("Validation/Process in Progress for the Uploaded list.Please do the Uploads post Validation/Process");
return false;
<%}%>