# Number format exception

Tags: java, exception, number-formatting

```
String tableChFlag=" ";   
<%if(tableChFlag.equals("Y")){%>
System.out.println("tableChFlag.equals("Y")");
alert("Validation/Process in Progress for the Uploaded list.Please do the Uploads post        Validation/Process");
return false;
<%}%>
```

this is the code i am getting as "numberformatexception".can u say where should i change the code?

Comment: I guess you refer this 1st : http://goo.gl/LleLQ

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363158/number-format-exception

Comment: Somewhere else. Look at the stacktrace and identify the code unit that *really* throws the exception.

Answer (score 2):

The NumberFormat Exception is not coming due to lines of code pasted by you as no number is being parsed here

Please use format blocks to format your code.